# Loading large Rasters into PostGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, raster2pgsql

I've been trying to load large Rasters into PostGIS using raster2pgsql command, however since it executes under one process, it always seems to be bound by the CPU of the vCore it's scheduled under.

Couldn't find a straightforward way to parallel process the tif and write it to PostGIS. Are there any cool ways to load large Rasters into PostGIS?